# Want to play .wav audio file on Raspberrypi Python 3 Shell IDLE

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi3, pyglet, pyaudio

I have installed many libraries and tried many different codes but I'm not able to **play the audio file on Raspberry Pi 3B+**.  If you know any method or have any code. Must recommend me.

Comment: ***I have installed many libraries and tried many different codes***: Which ones? Please be specific. `pyAudio` and `pygame` let you play music files.

Comment: @PedroLobito , used `pyAudio`,`pygame` & `pyglet`.

Comment: And what errors did you get? There's no point in saying ***it didn't work***, if you don't specify the error which didn't allow the script to run properly. That's called debugging, a coder's life.

Comment: @PedroLobito, thanks for your advice. I debugged my code.

Answer (score 0):

To Play a `wav` file on `raspberry` you can use `pygame`,i.e.:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
pygame.display.set_mode(pygame.display.list_modes()[-1]) # smallest resolution available
pygame.mixer.init()
pygame.mixer.music.load('file.wav')
pygame.mixer.music.play()

while pygame.mixer.music.get_busy():
    pygame.time.Clock().tick(10)
```

---

**Notes:**

- [pygame.mixer.music](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/music.html#pygame.mixer.music)
- I was able to play music with `pygame` **only** after creating a
  `display`.